# QPainterpath return null in operator subtraced

Tags: qt

I have a problem in qpainterpaht calculation.

Here are the two QPainterPath:

The two path: subjectpath, clippath. 
One edge is overlapping in math, but maybe not in computer data

[the path data and the schematic diagram][1]

Accordint to qpainterpath doc, the result of (subjectpath - clippath) should be  subjectpath. But the result in my code is null.

Would someone give me some advise?

Thank you!

here is the code:

```
double dy_x = -0.8609277780573142;
double dy_y = -179.18974019701932;
double dx_x = -100.56567051873533;
double dx_y = 0.48317375299134985;

double p1_x = 174.49572649572647;
double p1_y = 239.04273504273505;
double p2_x = 297.57264957264954;
double p2_y = 238.4957264957265;
QPainterPath p1;
p1.moveTo(p1_x, p1_y);
p1.lineTo(p1_x - dy_x + dx_x, p1_y - dy_y + dx_y);
p1.lineTo(p2_x - dy_x - dx_x, p2_y - dy_y - dx_y);
p1.lineTo(p2_x, p2_y);
p1.lineTo(p1_x, p1_y);
QPainterPath p2;
p2.moveTo(p1_x, p1_y);
p2.lineTo(p1_x + dy_x + dx_x, p1_y + dy_y + dx_y);
p2.lineTo(p2_x + dy_x - dx_x, p2_y + dy_y - dx_y);
p2.lineTo(p2_x, p2_y);
p2.lineTo(p1_x, p1_y);


double r1_x = 201.2991452991453;
double r1_y = 199.11111111111106;
double r2_x = 225.36752136752136;
double r2_y = 259.8290598290598;
double r3_x = 248.3418803418803;
double r3_y = 198.01709401709397;
QPainterPath p3;
p3.moveTo(r1_x, r1_y);
p3.lineTo(r2_x, r2_y);
p3.lineTo(r3_x, r3_y);
p3.lineTo(r1_x, r1_y);

QPainterPath result = (p3 & p1) - p2;
if (result.isEmpty()) {
    qDebug()<<"Result is empty";
}
else {
    qDebug()<<"Result is not empty";
}
```

[the code diagram, the result should be the orange part!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvrJV.png)

if r2_y = 252.8290598290598, the result should be right.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Please show your code.  Preferably a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you very much! @G.M. I posted the example code and the data. It reproduced in my system(Debian9， Qt5.9.3 and Qt5.11.2 both)